# PHP/MySQL - select all rows where a field is unique

Tags: php, mysql, select, unique

I have a table like this:

```
column_a  column_b
  foo        1
  bar        1
  bar        2
  baz        4
```

I'd like to have following result, containig all rows, that have a unique field value in `column_b`:

```
  bar        2
  baz        4
```

`foo`(0) and `bar`(1) both have the `column_b` value '1', so the '1' is not unique.
Is there a MySQL-Expression that filters all rows that have a unique `column_b`?

Maybe something like that:

```
select * from table where isunique(column_b)
```

In Addition: I do not need something like `DISTINCT`!

**edit (solved):**

Thanks to YaK and jcho360, this one is the solution:

```
select column_a, column_b from table group by column_b having count(column_b) = 1
```

OR

```
select column_a, column_b, COUNT(1) AS total from table group by column_b having total = 1
```

(thx to andrewtweber)

Comment: These answers help you? mark one as correct

Comment: @Nikolai Wüstemann: No problem, but I wouldn't mind a +1 instead ;)

Comment: Oh my bad, I think you need more reputation to do that.

Comment: No I have enough and I did my job! ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the count function will provide a selection where the value in column_b only occurs once. Try this:

```
select * from table group by (column_b) having count(column_b) = 1;
```

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(column_b) = 1` should suffice, because if there is no row, then it is not included in the result at all.
Even worse if your `column_b` contains NULL values: then their COUNT() equals 0, and will be returned (with a "random" value as `column_a` value)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT column_a, column_b, COUNT(1) AS total
FROM table
GROUP BY column_b
HAVING total = 1
```

I believe that should work. This groups all column_b together and counts how many have that particular value, then limits the result set to those with a unique column_b value.

Answer (score -1):

Try `select unique(column_b), column_a, from table` instead? :)

Edit fix typo

Comment: -1: in which version did they introduce the `UNIQUE()` function?

Comment: Whoops my bad, was thinking Oracle syntax where unique works as distinct :(